# When is it preferable to issue a warning to a user, rather than an error?

Tags: error-handling

I am writing a semi-complex piece of scientific software. We offer our end users many configuration options for each job and allow users to specify configurations only partially, with reasonable/safe defaults inferred for the other values.

Sometimes the inferred defaults combine pathologically with the specified options in that they are likely to make the job take a very long time or are likely to exceed memory or scratch disk space. However, these configurations are still well-defined and partial results can be useful. It is possible to detect when this is the case.

Would it be better in such cases to issue and log a *warning* and allow the job to continue, or to stop it and issue an *error* that blocks the job until better values are chosen or the inferred values are specified manually by the user (as an override)?

More generally, are there any rules of thumb as to when it might be preferable to issue fatal errors over warnings in recoverable situations?

Comment: The only sensible answer here is "it depends". You need to ask the users or domain experts what would be most useful for them.

Comment: Could you show  a pop-up window with the  issue description (eg, the expected execution time, memory requirement) and let the user decide whether to proceed? Another approach is in Adobe software: they show a panel with issues, coloured red for fatal errors and yellow for warnings.

Comment: @Tupolev._ -- Adobe's approach sounds interesting. I'll have to look in to that, since I haven't used Creative Cloud myself

Comment: @DocBrown - I think "Should I warn or fail when a resource is likely to be exhausted?" is an abstract enough question. If the background to my question is distracting, I'm glad to remove it.

Comment: @AlexReinking: removing your question's background would make it probably so broad it will get closed shortly  with the predefined "too broad" close reason. Just because you wish there is a general easy answer, that does not make it true.  You have to make an analysis what consequences, pros/cons the "warning" or "error" alternatives will have in the context of your specific domain, and for your audience.

Comment: I suggest displaying the estimated time of completion along with a cancel button.  Always. That way you don’t need a separate use case. And it puts the user in control without forcing him to make a decision to continue.

Answer (score 4):

(Expanding on my comment.) It can be hard to know beforehand what is "a very long time" for a particular user. Where do you draw the line? If a job inputs are valid and can be useful for the user, they may be willing to wait a while. Perhaps it's best to let the user decide themselves.

One approach is to show a modal pop-up window with the  issue description (eg, expected job duration or memory requirement). The user will have to explicitly cancel or continue the job.

A less invasive approach, taken  by the Adobe apps, is to show an "Issues" panel. Among those, fatal errors are shown in red. These have to be resolved. Warnings are shown in yellow, with ways to fix them. If the user doesn't fix particular warnings, the presumption is they are happy to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes the inferred defaults combine pathologically with the specified options

For this particular issue, it's a broader problem of configuration ergonomic.

Let's imagine for example you are configuring a container which has a block size and a number of blocks. You know the total memory size is going to be size * number. If you simply allow each to be set independently, you will have problems when both are set to maximum while it can be OK one is maxed if the other is below a threshold.

These instances of configuration dependency must be held with a lot of caution. An inexperienced user might tweak things without specific knowledge of the impact of both combined. You have several choices that don't involve throwing errors to make the configuration more ergonomic :

- Change the way it is configured to make each configuration independent. In my example, if for example I set block size and total size instead, I can't be wrong if reasonable ranges are set for both.
- Explicit dependency in the UI. So for example display them on a configuration pages where both are displayed, and where total memory is displayed in real time as well (similar to price on complex pricing products).
- Hide configuration complexity. If your users are too prone to mistakes, it can be simply because your configuration is too complex to handle. Then you could limit to preset options, like "Container capacity: low / medium / high".

Answer (score 0):

Warn that it is slow, and show how to tweak the configuration in order to gain speed,
very concrete with the submitter's value. With a marker **now-optimized**.
Also provide a **resubmit-and-force-execution** parameter. In order that the forcing is rarely chosen, the shown alternatives should be attractive. Maybe show guessed estimated times/percentages.

For this to be fruitful, maintain a repeatable history/log. To search for (possible) optimization candidates, and verify your optimisation proposals.

The advantages are client satisfaction and server capacity.